# To check whether an entered value exists in a List

Tags: python

This is my simple code. When a User enters a value, it has to be compared with the list I have used and should return the output as required. But when I execute the code and enter a value that is a part of the list, it returns the print statement under the else construct. Please help me with your suggestions

```
mylist=[1,2,3]
print('Enter the Rank:')
x=input()
if x in mylist:
    print('You have passed')
else:
    print('Sorry you have failed')
```

Comment: `input` returns strings, not integers

Comment: x=`int(input()` if you are expecting int vlaue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in mylist are ints. Input returns a string, so to compare them you need to convert one of them.
Either

```
x = int(input())
```

or

```
if int(x) in mylist
```

Comment: Thanks. So the input() accepts only a string. Thanks for enlightening me

Comment: No, it does not accept a string, it returns a string no matter what you type.